# class member function definition after forward declaration of class, before class declaration

Tags: c++

i got below compilation problem, while defining member function. is there a way to define member function before class declaration but with forward declaration?

> error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class GetErrorLogInterfaceTest’

```
class GetErrorLogInterfaceTest; // forward declaration of class
void GetErrorLogInterfaceTest::initializeJsonFile() { // member function definition
}
class GetErrorLogInterfaceTest : public ::testing::Test {
public:
    void initializeJsonFile(); // member function declaration
 }
```

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible to define member functions of incomplete classes. It is only possible to define member functions of those classes that have been defined. A forward declaration is not sufficient.

The standard says in [class.mfct]:

> A member function may be defined (11.4) in its class definition, in which case it is an inline member
>   function (10.1.6), or it may be defined outside of its class definition **if it has already been declared** but not
>   defined **in its class definition**. ...

Now, the rule does *not* say that member functions may *only* be defined in these two places, so unless you know that standard has no other rule which allows a member function definition somewhere else (which it doesn't, as far as I know), then this by itself isn't technically complete information.

However, the paragraph continues

> ... Except for member function definitions
>   that appear outside of a class definition, and except for explicit specializations of member functions of class
>   templates and member function templates (17.8) appearing outside of the class definition, a member function
>   shall not be redeclared.

Note that a member function shall not be *redeclared* within the class definition. If the member function were defined before the class definition, then the function declaration within the class definition would be a *redeclaration*, and would violate this rule.

Answer (score 1):

No. The standard covers this trivial aspect as well.

From CPP draft (N4713)

> **12.2.1 Member functions [class.mfct]**
>
> 1. **A member function may be defined in its class definition**, in which case it is an inline member function, or it may be **defined outside of its class definition if it has already been declared but not defined in its class definition**.

So the class definition is first necessary to define the member function in either one of the ways mentioned above.